# How to set Compiler Compliance level in Jenkins job?

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I wanted to use JDK11 for my project but want to set Compiler compliance at level 1.8. I can achieve this in eclipse like this,
[image: JDK Compliance option in Eclipse]

Here is my **POM.xml**

[image]

Is there such setting in Jenkins? How to tell Jenkins to use specific JDK compliance level?

Here is how i am specifying the JDK in **Jenkins**. Now, How to tell Jenkins to set Compliance level to 1.8 ??

[image]

Comment: You already have Java version 8 set in your `pom.xml` and running Maven with a higher Java version, such as Java 11, should work as long as you do not use any parts of the system library that have been removed after the Java 8 release. How did you specify your Jenkins job, with or without a pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I have created/specified a Jenkins job as "Maven project". The build was successful (with JDK 11 set in Jenkins and java version 8 set in pom.xml). Does that mean i am using JDK11 with java8 compiler ?

Comment: Maven probably uses here `javac` of the Java 11 JDK with which you run Maven with the option `--release 8` to create Java 8 bytecode and to give errors when things of the system library are used that was added in Java 9, 10 or 11.